# add color to a cursor: url("data:image)

Tags: css, svg

How do I add a color to an SVG cursor in the existing CSS

```
html {
    cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='32px' height='32px' viewBox='0 0 512 512' style='enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;' xml:space='preserve'%3E %3Cpath d='M127 64A63 63 0 0 1 64 127 63 63 0 0 1 1 64 63 63 0 0 1 64 1 63 63 0 0 1 127 64Z'/%3E %3C/svg%3E"), pointer;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add fill attribute to **fill='red'**

```
html { cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='32px' height='32px' viewBox='0 0 512 512' style='enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;' xml:space='preserve'%3E %3Cpath fill='red' d='M127 64A63 63 0 0 1 64 127 63 63 0 0 1 1 64 63 63 0 0 1 64 1 63 63 0 0 1 127 64Z'/%3E %3C/svg%3E"), pointer;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `fill` attribute. but make sure use single quote when give fill attribute.

```css
html { cursor: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' id='Layer_1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' x='0px' y='0px' width='32px' height='32px' viewBox='0 0 512 512' fill='red' style='enable-background:new 0 0 512 512;' xml:space='preserve'%3E %3Cpath d='M127 64A63 63 0 0 1 64 127 63 63 0 0 1 1 64 63 63 0 0 1 64 1 63 63 0 0 1 127 64Z'/%3E %3C/svg%3E"), pointer;

}
```